# Neo4j: How to delete all nodes and relationships beyond a node?

Tags: neo4j

Here's a simple graph:

```
(:a)-[:r]->(:b)
```

If want to to delete `(:b)`, I can do this with:

```
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b :b)
DELETE a, r, b
```

---

However, `(b)` can have multiple relationships and nodes coming off of it (and those nodes can recursively have more relationships and nodes too). Something like this:

```
(:a)-[:r]->(:b)-[:s]->(x)-[:r]->(y)- ... ->(z)
```

How can I recursively delete every node and relationship beyond `(b)`?

Comment: Note that if you omit the colon in Cypher, you specify the _variable_ and not the _label_. Hence, your query does not only delete `(:a)-[:r]->(:b)` subgraphs, but all `(...)-[...]-(:b)` subgraph, where the source node and the edge can have arbitrary labels. Instead, you would want `MATCH (a:a)-[r:r]->(b:b) DELETE a, r, b`

Comment: Just to clarify, is there a specific node `b` that you want to delete (as well as its connected subgraph), or do you want to do this for all nodes with the label `:b`? If you only want to delete a specific `b` node and its subgraph, what differentiates this node from others of the `:b` label? Is it a `name` property? Some other property?

Comment: @InverseFalcon Yes, there is a specific `:b` node, and it has a property with a unique index value. Sorry about the confusion; I tried to make the example code as simple as possible (but obviously it was a little too simple! )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DETACH DELETE is going to be useful here. This first deletes all relationships from a node, then deletes the node itself. That makes your query easier, as all you need is a query for all nodes reachable from your b node.

I'm going to assume for the moment that this `b` node in your question is a specific node, instead of every single node with the label `:b`. I do encourage you to reread the developer documentation on variables and labels, as I'm guessing there's a little confusion here.

So, assuming a specific b node, and assuming that it has a name property that differentiates it, you might use this query to delete it and the entire subgraph connected to it and reachable from it.

```
MATCH (b:b)-[*0..]-(x)
WHERE b.name = 'b'
WITH DISTINCT x
DETACH DELETE x
```

Note that because we don't care about the relationship type, and because we've specified 0 or more relationships, x will match to b and its entire connected subgraph no matter how many relationships away. Detaching and deleting x will delete all relationships in the subgraph and then all nodes in the subgraph.

Comment: The above query deletes all ancestors as well as descendants even after specifying a direction which is not good at all. I wonder why?

Comment: That shouldn't be the case, if a direction is added it should only be expanding in the specified direction. If you have a particular graph on which you can recreate this, can you create a separate question then provide the link here?

Answer (score 1):

To delete recursively from a node, you can use [path variables](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#_assigning_to_path_variables): `p=(source)-[type*minimumHops..maximumHops]->(target)` (by default, `minimumHops` is 1).

Example dataset:

```
CREATE
  (a:a)-[:r]->(b:b),
  (b)-[:r]->(c:c),
  (c)-[:r]->(d:d),
  (b)-[:r]->(e:e)
```

Query:

```
MATCH (a:a)-[r:r]->(b:b)
OPTIONAL MATCH p=(b)-[:r*]->(c)
DELETE a, r, b, p
```

An alternative, equivalent query:

```
MATCH
  (a:a)-[r:r]->(b:b),
  p=(b)-[:r*0..]->(c)
DELETE a, r, p
```

It's worth noting that both will work in the cornercase where you only have a single `(:a)-[:r]->(:b)` edge in your graph. The first query does this by specifying the path in an `OPTIONAL MATCH`, while the second one does it by allowing paths of zero hops.